# Rationale for the added whitespace in global site (left panel)?

Tags: discussion, support

I have noticed that many sites now come with a left panel, for example:

[image]

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309349/left-nav-responsive-design-and-theming-next-steps) might be one of the announcement posts on `stackexchange`.

Seaching [this tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/left-navigation) I find many hits such as [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369106/how-do-i-hide-the-left-navigation-sidebar)  (I restricted to `stackoverflow` for not particular reason).

I see a very good rationale for this opened space on the left: to add advertisements.

Because I use AdBlockPlus I may not get the normal view of the other sites. So far it seems tex.stackexchange has not changed its design. Is it coming to us? If yes will it be possible to disable it entirely?

#### Update:

[This link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness) seems to be the main one for discussion on meta site.

Comment: It is possible to permanently disable it. At the moment this has to be done for each site separately.

Comment: The plan is to align all site designs: the Powers have found that 'personalised' set ups are not scalable for them ...

Comment: in the mean time a global disable option was added, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311528/237989

Comment: @samcarter as this answers the non-digressive part of my question, if you make it an answer I will accept it. I am surprised I did not get any close flag yet, maybe I am starting to get scary enough.

Comment: @jfbu I added a short answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left navigation bar seems to be planed also for our site, but don't worry, it is easy to disable it. Go to your profile page and edit the preferences:

[image]

At the moment this has to be done for each site separately, but [Hide Left nav everywhere with a global preference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311528/237989) indicates that it will be possible to globally disable the navigation bar.